# Get all elements in an array from category and subcategories arrays

Tags: php, arrays, categories

I'm programming in PHP and I've these arrays:

**Category array:**

```
$type = array("fruit","veggie","other");
```

**Subcategory arrays:**

```
$fruit=array("apple","orange");
$veggie=array("bean","pea");
$other=array("bread","cake");
```

I can get all the elements of the subcategories with:

```
$all_elements = array_merge($fruit,$veggie,$other);
```

But this expressions has the problem that if I've to create new categories I've to rewrite the expression.

I'd like to know how I can get an expression like next one to get the same result:

```
$all_elements = array_merge(SOMETHING($type));
```

Thanks in advance!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at **[compact](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php)**:

> compact — Create array containing variables and their values

So you want to do:

```
$type = array("fruit","veggie","other");
$fruit=array("apple","orange");
$veggie=array("bean","pea");
$other=array("bread","cake");

print_r(compact(($type)));
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [fruit] => Array
        (
            [0] => apple
            [1] => orange
        )

    [veggie] => Array
        (
            [0] => bean
            [1] => pea
        )

    [other] => Array
        (
            [0] => bread
            [1] => cake
        )

)
```

However, I recommend you to do it completly differently, as @Rasclatt suggested:

```
$food['fruit'][]    =   'apple';
$food['fruit'][]    =   'orange';
$food['veggie'][]   =   'bean';
$food['veggie'][]   =   'pea';
$food['other'][]    =   'bread';
$food['other'][]    =   'cake';
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I would create one array that you can add to. You can more easily merge and handle new categories. You can loop through the array to get types and sub-types.

```
$food['fruit'][]    =   'apple';
$food['fruit'][]    =   'orange';
$food['veggie'][]   =   'bean';
$food['veggie'][]   =   'pea';
$food['other'][]    =   'bread';
$food['other'][]    =   'cake';
```

Answer (score 0):

I would layout the data differently:

```
 $item["fruit"]=array("apple","orange");
 $item["veggie"]=array("bean","pea");
 $item["other"]=array("bread","cake");
```

So if you want `$all_elements` you could just ask for `$item` instead:

```
print_r ($item);
```

And if you want a certain category:

```
print_r ($item["veggie"]);
```